my custom slider implementation isn't a valid override of 'SliderComponentShape.paint'
I'm using dart code v3.86.0.
I'm attempting to make a custom thumb for a slider in flutter, with little success. I get the error:my custom slider implementation isn't a valid override of 'SliderComponentShape.paint'
and have mad esur ethe signature is correct and yet it doenst work.
This i smy full code:

class _CustomThumbShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return Size.fromRadius(18);
  }

  String _formatTime(double value) {
    int hours = value.floor();
    int minutes = ((value - hours) * 60).round();
    return '${hours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset thumbCenter, {
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required Animation<double> valueAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(thumbCenter, 18, paint); // Drawing at 'thumbCenter'

    // TextSpan for displaying time based on the slider's value
    TextSpan span = TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      text: _formatTime(enableAnimation.value), // Displaying time dynamically
    );

    TextPainter tp = TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.center);

    tp.layout();

    Offset textCenter = Offset(
        thumbCenter.dx - (tp.width / 2), thumbCenter.dy - (tp.height / 2));

    tp.paint(canvas, textCenter);
  }
}

and this is the full error message:

'_CustomThumbShape.paint' ('void Function(PaintingContext, Offset, {required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required bool isDiscrete, required TextPainter labelPainter, required RenderBox parentBox, required Size sizeWithOverflow, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required double textScaleFactor, required double value, required Animation<double> valueAnimation})') isn't a valid override of 'SliderComponentShape.paint' ('void Function(PaintingContext, Offset, {required Animation<double> activationAnimation, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, required bool isDiscrete, required TextPainter labelPainter, required RenderBox parentBox, required Size sizeWithOverflow, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required double textScaleFactor, required double value})').dartinvalid_override

Any help would be very much appreciated!
I've tried fixing the signature, to what it says on the documentation, to no avail. The error persits.

I had the same problem but solved it.
The problem with the paint import is that Size and OffSet have to be used from the dart.ui. I do not use SliderComponentShape but the same applies.
My example is
 import 'dart:ui' as ui;
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class CustomSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {
  const CustomSliderTrackShape();

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double trackHeight = 24.0;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final double trackTop =
        offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, ui.Offset offset,
      {required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required ui.Offset thumbCenter,
      ui.Offset? secondaryOffset,
      bool isEnabled = false,
      bool isDiscrete = false,
      required ui.TextDirection textDirection}) {
    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );
    final Paint backgroundPaint = Paint()
      ..color = AppColors.containerWhite
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    // Draw the background
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        trackRect,
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(12),
        bottomRight: const Radius.circular(12),
      ),
      backgroundPaint,
    );

    final Paint activePaint = Paint()
      ..color = AppColors.containerBlue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()
      ..color = AppColors.containerWhite
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final RRect activeTrackRRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      Rect.fromLTRB(
          trackRect.left, trackRect.top, thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.bottom),
      topLeft: const Radius.circular(15),
      bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(15),
    );

    final RRect inactiveTrackRRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
      Rect.fromLTRB(
          thumbCenter.dx, trackRect.top, trackRect.right, trackRect.bottom),
      topRight: const Radius.circular(15),
      bottomRight: const Radius.circular(15),
    );

    context.canvas.drawRRect(activeTrackRRect, activePaint);
    context.canvas.drawRRect(inactiveTrackRRect, inactivePaint);

    // Draw the border for the entire track
    final Paint borderPaint = Paint()
      ..color = AppColors.containerBlue
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        trackRect,
        topLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
        bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(12),
        topRight: const Radius.circular(12),
        bottomRight: const Radius.circular(12),
      ),
      borderPaint,
    );
  }
}


According to the documentation you don't use the same signature for the paint method of the SliderComponentShape class
Can you try with this signature and tell me if it works?
@override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset thumbCenter,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(thumbCenter, 18, paint); // Drawing at 'thumbCenter'

    // TextSpan for displaying time based on the slider's value
    TextSpan span = TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      text: _formatTime(enableAnimation.value), // Displaying time dynamically
    );

    TextPainter tp = TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.center);

    tp.layout();

    Offset textCenter = Offset(
        thumbCenter.dx - (tp.width / 2), thumbCenter.dy - (tp.height / 2));

    tp.paint(canvas, textCenter);
  }


Hello, thank you for your answer. Even with your signature, i still get the same error: dart(invalid_override)

Did you copy and paste the entire paint method from my previous answer?

I did, nothing seemed to change

What is your Flutter version?

3.16.5, apologies for the tardy reply.
